# I did a javascript coding to fill in text, it did filled the value in html code, but doesn't reflect on the website (the fill column still empty)

Tags: javascript

I did a javascript to fill in textfield, it did update the value in HTML code, but it doesn't reflect on the webpage fill column

I entered the text (by typing in manually) in the fill column to confirm the value is updating the element that I am targeting to use javascript to fill in the value. my javascript managed to update the value, but it just won't reflect on the webpage fill column

This is the HTML code for the webpage:-

```
<div class="next-table-cell-wrapper">
  <span class="myinput-wrap">
   <span class="next-input next-input-single next-input-medium error  error" style="width: 100%;">
   <input type="text" min="0" placeholder="<=24.05" value="24.04" height="100%" data-spm-anchor-id="a2o7i.11278553.old-navigation.i42.1a041e13fbm6Y1">
   </span>
   <span class="error-info">Empty, please fill in.</span></span></div>
```

This s my javascript code:

```
var fillBox = document.querySelectorAll('div.next-table-cell-wrapper input[type=text]')
fillBox[0].attributes[3].value = "24.04"
```

but webpage fill column still showing an error message:

> Empty, please fill in

Comment: `.attributes[3].value` ... well, that looks wrong ... attributes array on an element?? What happens if you `fillBox[0].value = "24.04"` instead? or `document.querySelector('div.next-table-cell-wrapper input[type=text]').value = "24.04"`

Comment: you're also not even touching `<span class="error-info">Empty, please fill in.</span>` ... so, that's not going away as if by majicks

Comment: now the value is reflected in the fill column, but the submit button still disable not allowing me to click, what step i have missed out?

Comment: if i try to key in a value manually in the fill column example a value "24.05" and then i initiate the code document.querySelector('div.next-table-cell-wrapper input[type=text]').value = "24.04" , it shows that the fill column becoming "24.04", but when i click any place out side the fill column, it returns back to "24.05", any idea what had happened?